# How to change python script to .exe with user defined input and output paths in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, exe

I have python script , i want to change this simple script to .exe file with user defined input and output path .

in below script 'csv' is input folder and contain multiple txt files ,

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os 
for file in os.listdir('csv/'):
    filename = 'csv/{}'.format(file)
    print(filename)

    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    df.to_csv(path_out)
```

Comment: You can look at Pyinstaller - https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: for python 3.6 not working pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

A simple way you can do this with cx_freeze is as follows:

1. conda install -c conda-forge cx_freeze, or pip install cx_freeze to your env with numpy and pandas
2. Make a folder called dist for your new .exe
3. Save the code below as csv_thing.py, or whatever you want it to be called.
4. Run the command: cxfreeze csv_thing.py --target-dir C:\somepath\dist
5. There is a good chance that without using a cx_freeze setup file (spec file in pyinstaller) that not all of the files will get copied over to the dist dir. Numpy and pandas from Anaconda envs are often tricky.
6. If file failure occurs, you can manually copy the .dll files over into the dist folder; it's easy if you just grab them all. If you're using an Anaconda env, they likely live here: C:\Users\your_user_account\Anaconda3\envs\panel\Library\bin. Otherwise grab all of them from the numpy location: C:\Users\matth\Anaconda3\envs\panel\Lib\site-packages\numpy and copy to the dist dir.

---

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import os   

in_dir = input(' enter a folder path where your .csvs are located: ')  
out_dir = input(' enter a folder path where your .csvs will go: ')  

csv_list = [os.path.join(in_dir, fn) for fn in next(os.walk(in_dir))[2]if fn.endswith('.csv')]  

for csv in csv_list:  
    file_name = os.path.basename(csv)  
    print(file_name)

    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(out_dir, file_name))
```